# big query dataset not found, but shows in listing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to remove a dataset from BigQuery, but it seem that cannot find it. The dataset is listed using the `bq ls` command:

```sh
$ bq ls

datasetId  
----------- 
  flights
```

However, when I try removing it with the command `bq rm` the below behavior happens:

```sh
$ bq rm flights

BigQuery error in rm operation: Not found: Dataset $projectID:flights
```

I have redacted the project ID.

Comment: It is not expected. Could you create a bug to BigQuery here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers?

Comment: I just tested this and it works as expected. Dataset is successfully removed/deleted. What version of the `bq` client are using? I'm on 2.0.52. To find your version, run: `bq version`.

Comment: I made a simple test creating and deleting a dataset [1], which worked as intended. This issue could be caused by an old version of the `bq` client. You can update it to the latest version using the command [`gcloud components update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update).
[1]:
$ bq version
This is BigQuery CLI 2.0.52
$ bq ls
*Empty result*
$ bq mk TEST
Dataset '<PROJECT ID>:TEST' successfully created.
$ bq ls
      datasetId
 -------------------
  TEST
$ bq rm TEST
rm: remove dataset '<PROJECT ID>:TEST'? (y/N) y
$ bq ls
*Empty result*

Comment: I will try updating the client and seeing

Comment: @YunZhang from the docs[https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages] on this I saw the below message
`Fix the resource names or wait at least 6 hours after streaming before querying a deleted table.`
After waiting that amount of time I am able to remove the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#notFound), I saw the below message:

> Fix the resource names or wait at least 6 hours after streaming before querying a deleted table.

After waiting that amount of time, I was able to remove the dataset.